# How to break URL links that include long alphanumerical strings?

Tags: urls

How to break url links that include long alphanumerical strings?

Here an example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{article}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{ref.bib}
@misc{Reuters_2023,
  author = "Reuters",
  title  = "Example of long URL",
  year   = 2023,
  url    = "https://www.facebook.com/Reuters/posts/pfbid0Gw8qyhJSCCBeAzfVRXcV9aMBsy5pzmeTfbx2WeTmGySdpSYPBxtqJqkkuhDX9Fb9l",
}
\end{filecontents}


\usepackage{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\usepackage[hyphens,spaces,obeyspaces]{url}

\begin{document}
\cite{Reuters_2023}
\bibliography{ref}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: One classical alternative is `\usepackage{xurl}`.

Comment: As gusbrs say use `xurl` instead, this changes `\url`, which (hopefully) is used by the style you use, to allow linebreaks more or less everywhere. With all the long URLs we use nowadays it is better to use `xurl`.

Comment: Thanks a lot to both! It works perfectly! If you write your comment(s) in the "Answer" section, I will accept the Answer!

Comment: @gusbrs would you provide an answer?

Comment: @daleif Mhm, except that I can't make it work. Apparently `apacite` does use `\url`, but has its own url breakpoints settings. So, anyone who can make it work, please feel free to answer.

Comment: @gusbrs you're right, I don't think one can use `xurl` with `apacite` in its current form. (But since `apacite` looks for loaded `url` at begin document, one could delay `xurl`: `\AtBeginDocument{\usepackage{xurl}}` loaded after `apacite`, that does seem to work)

Comment: @daleif It's stretching things a bit, but I guess it's what can be done, short of using a different style. But, go ahead, since you found a way to make it work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `apacite` package detects `url` being loaded and then changes it. Thus any changes made by `xurl` might be gone. However, if we instead loads `xurl` via

```
\usepackage{apacite}
\AtBeginDocument{\usepackage{xurl}}
```

instead of loading `url`, `xurl` is actually loaded after `apacite`'s check for `url` and its changes are never applied.

It is a bit hackish... Also note that `apacite` does not seem to have been updated in almost 10years, so no wonder it has no support for `xurl`.

Comment: I am very grateful, thanks a lot to you and to @gusbrs!!! :-)